# How to stage forms in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have form data that I gather in the views. What the user inputs will determine what the next form will be like. Should I create another view? If so, how do I pass on variables from one view to another? And should the separate view render a different html page?

Or is there a way to work in the same view that I gathered the data initially?

The view looks like this:

```
def admission(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DeterminingForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            selected_season = form.cleaned_data['season']
            selected_batch = form.cleaned_data['batch']
    form = DeterminingForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'admission.html', context)
```

Comment: Django used to include a form wizard for the purpose of multi-step forms/views, it's now been moved to a separate project https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html

Answer (score 1):

I have used [django-formtools](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) Form wizard in the past for similar use cases. Subclassing out the SessionWizardView allows you to render multiple different forms using the same view and even the same template if you wish, however you can have a different template for each form. The variables for each form submission are stored in server-side sessions and the context can be extracted for each step in the process.

If the sequence of forms is different dependent on the answers in the previous form, you should be able to build up some logic within the process using the WizardView.get_form() method for each form step in the process. Hope this helps as a starter